# How to add Product into cart and get it in another Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I am getting data in my android app through jsonarray in listView, when I  click on listview item, it  will open another activity with detail of that item, in this activity i have an button Add to cart, when I am click on this button, the product is going in cart in new activity but when I am pressing back button for add new product, and again click  on add to cart button, my first product was replaced with second  product. I also add listView and listViewAdapter for CartActivity.

**CartActivity**

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
String item_name;
String item_price;
String image;
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
public int counter = 1;
public int sum = 0;
public int quantity;
ImageView ivAdd;
ImageView ivMinus;
TextView numberItem;
TextView txtTotalPrice;
Button btnAddCart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
    setTitle("Add to cart");
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    item_name = intent.getStringExtra("item_name");
    item_price = intent.getStringExtra("item_price");
    image = intent.getStringExtra("image");
    sum = Integer.parseInt(item_price);
    TextView itemName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView itemPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
    ImageView itemImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    txtTotalPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotalTag);
    numberItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNumberItem);
    ivMinus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivMinus);
    ivAdd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAdd);
    btnAddCart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCart);

    itemName.setText(item_name);
    itemPrice.setText(item_price);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(image, itemImage);
    txtTotalPrice.setText(item_price);

    ivAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    ivMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAddCart.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == btnAddCart) {

        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", item_name);
        bundle.putString("price", item_price);
        bundle.putInt("quantity", counter);
        bundle.putInt("total", sum);
        Intent intent = new Intent(SouthCartActivity.this, CheckoutActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

**CheckoutActivity**

```
public class CheckoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static ListView listView;
CheckoutAdapter adapter;
String item_name[];
String item_price[];
int item_quantity[];
int item_total[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkout);
    setTitle("Checkout");
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    item_name = new String[]{bundle.getString("name")};
    item_price = new String[]{bundle.getString("price")};
    item_quantity = new int[]{bundle.getInt("quantity")};
    item_total = new int[]{bundle.getInt("total")};

    adapter = new CheckoutAdapter(this, item_name, item_price, item_quantity, item_total);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: You are not saving any item selected in the CheckoutActivity, so every time you start this activity you will replace your last selection for the new one.

Comment: how can i save it, i have done many things but the same problem, please explain me..

Comment: If you want to have all the selections even if you close the app you will have to use a database or SharedPreference to save the selections. And in your adapter you will have to pass a list of objects which contains an item_name, item_price, item_quality and item_total.

Comment: thank  you.... i implement this and its working...